# How can I install a supersu root zip on a system.img to create a pre-rooted system?

Tags: rooting, root-access, supersu, factory-image

I'm looking to create a pre-rooted system.img for a specific device. running Marshmellow (6.0) on ARM.
I have a SuperSU zip for marshmellow and the compiled system.img for my device.

OK. I know you cant flash a zip to a .img - but, can i decompile the img, add the resources, and recompile?

I specifically want to know -

1. Most importantly, is this possible...?
2. If yes, What files do I need from the zip?
3. How do I decompile the .img while not losing any important data?
4. Where in the decompiled .img do I put the files from the zip?
5. How do I create symlinks and set the permissions for the new files?
6. How do I recompile the .img maintaining all linux permissions etc.?

Note, working environment is preferably windows. (although if I can get detailed instructions for Ubuntu, that'd be great too.)

This question begs quite a detailed answer, and I'll be most grateful for any assistance on the subject, even incomplete.

The device in question happens to be a VN220LTE, but I assume that the approach would be generic.

Comment: Why are you targeting system image? Just modify the kernel like topjohnwu does using Magisk. This way, system image remains unmodified.

Comment: that would definitely be better, i've looked in to it, and downloaded his app. however, the device i am targeting does not have a know root method yet, nor a custom recovery, so correct me if im wrong - i dont think that is a viable option. my only hope is to create a firmware and flash it using lg update or flashtool

Comment: rooting is easy with Magisk, your problem is other. it's a Verizon device with locked bootloader, i doubt you can flash modified boot or system https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3668054

Comment: well itd be good to answer the question for reference purposes, as there doesnt exist a clear answer out ther, as far as i can tell, and its a pretty basic question  in the realm of custom roms